# What means this error in MongoDb running mongodb package for the first time?

Tags: mongodb

$ mongo

BadValue: error: no args for --configdb

try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongos.exe --help' for more information

mongod says waiting for connections on port 27017. Whats the problem with mongo?
My path to mongo is: alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongos.exe"

For everybody with the same problems of MongoDB installiation on Windows accordingly Udemy course of Full stack Bootcamp.
Download current version of Mongodb community server (msi) save it in Program files->Mongodb folder then you should download (https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-mongosh_1.5.1_amd64.deb) MongoDB shell because in 6.0 version or later there is no mongo.exe. save it to Mongodb folder. Save the variables mongod and mongosh via vim or interface tools (.dash_profile). I created via vim. Mongod variable is path to you mongod.exe and mongosh is the path to mongosh.exe. and run the mongod and mongosh in separate terminal tabs. For me it was necessary to rename mongorc.js to mongoshrc.js I used mv mongorc.js mongoshrc.js and that's all. Please be attention if you have old .bash_profile. You need to remove them (rm) because it grabs the first one. Check the list with ls -a.

Comment: `mongo.exe` is different from `mongos.exe`. And, `mongosh` is the replacement for the legacy `mongo`.

Comment: But after download there is just these .exe files like mongos and mongod.

Comment: `mongosh` is a separate download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the shell from latest version here:
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell?jmp=docs

mongo is change to mongosh, extract the folder in your desire directory, and change your "atlas mongos" path to "mongosh.exe" path. "mongosh.exe" path will be in bin folder of the downloaded zip file.